# Rails 6 + Ruby 2.7 - How can I track my videos/images uploads size so that I know total how much of MB files have been uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

MY **Rails 6** app uses **ruby@2.7** and `carrierwave` to upload images and videos.
Here I am looking for something like our basic Rails [counter_cache](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html) mechanism, which can help me ***track total size of uploads done by the user and total size remaining so far***.

The Rails app gives a default size of 1GB to every user to upload images/videos (*uploaded to S3*) and hence it is necessary to track and maintain every uploads size too, so that this mechanism will help to warn user that he has consumed the given limit and how much size is consumed/left for him.

**What I have done so far!**

Every `user` `has many` images and videos.
So on every upload, i trigger a callback in every `*_uploader.rb` class to get the `total file size` and **add** it with previous one already present in the `user.total_size_consumed`, having 0 as default value.

Just want to know if there is any other way to achieve the same as I also need to implement conversion too (MB/GB/TB) too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an upload item class and table?  You should add a field to that table `upload_size` and use the callback to store the upload size there.

This means when the user deletes an upload, you'll be able to reduce his total size of uploads by using a `before_destroy` callback in the item model.

You can also reset the total size of uploads for the user fairly easily... just the sum of `upload_size` for all upload items.

Comment: If I go by this approach, then I also have to add callbacks to all the key areas like - when user uploads, deletes/updates any uploaded item, when user changes his feature to increase the limit, then again a chain of updates is bound to happen....this will become very unmanageable once the app becomes huge. Any way to settle this out in advanced  way..like any service/middleware...to take care of it?

Comment: I don't see that. If you allow him only to create (upload a new file) and destroy (remove an existing file) then you're covered with your two callbacks.  If he changes the limit, so what?  It doesn't change the  `total_file_size`.  I assume if it's reduced you're not going to delete his uploads, so he'll have a negative allowance.